# Liferay 7 Module Project Spring MVC Portlet, No handler found error as there is no viewrendererservlet

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-ide, liferay-blade-cli

I was developing a simple spring mvc portlet using the blade CLI. I am getting the error as

> ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-9][render_portlet_jsp:131] null
>   org.springframework.web.portlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler
>   found for portlet request: mode 'view', phase 'RENDER_PHASE',
>   parameters map[[empty]]

I dont know how to resolve the issue. I also checked the following link but I am not sure how to fix it. 
https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-63801?_ga=1.195671916.133904790.1461624186
     Any help would be Appreciated. Thanks.

Please find the code below.

1.SpringController.java

```
package com.liferay.docs.mvcportlet.portlet.portlet;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.RenderMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.ResourceMapping;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import javax.portlet.ResourceRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
@Scope("prototype")
public class SpringController {

@RenderMapping
public ModelAndView preAssess(RenderRequest renderRequest,
        RenderResponse renderResponse) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("view");
    return mv;
}
}
```

2. MyMVCPortlet.java

   ```
   package com.liferay.docs.mvcportlet.portlet.portlet;

   import com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

   import javax.portlet.Portlet;
   import javax.portlet.PortletConfig;
   import javax.portlet.PortletException;

   import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
   import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
   import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
   import org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet;

   @Component(
   immediate = true,
   property = {
       "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample",
       "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=false",
       "javax.portlet.display-name=my-mvc-portlet-project Portlet",
       "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
       "javax.portlet.init-param.contextConfigLocation=/META-INF/spring-portlet.xml",
       "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
       "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user",
   },
   service = Portlet.class
   )
    public class MyMvcPortlet extends DispatcherPortlet  {

   @Override
       public void init(PortletConfig config) throws PortletException {
           super.init(config);
       }


   }
   ```
3. spring-portlet.xml

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>

     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context- 3.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base- package="com.liferay.docs.mvcportlet.portlet.portlet" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="viewClass"
       value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
        <bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
         id="messageSource" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="true">
         <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
         <!-- NOTE: cacheSeconds enable auto-reloading of properties. To turn off, 
            use "-1" -->
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1" />
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
               <value>content.languages</value>
            </list>
          </property>
      </bean>
      <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
      </bean>

       <bean id="localeResolver"
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
         <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="handlerMapping"
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMap ping">
           <property name="interceptors">
          <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
           </property>
        </bean>
       </beans>
   ```
4. build.gradle

   ```
   buildscript {
       dependencies {
           classpath group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.gradle.plugins", version: "1.0.369"
       }

       repositories {
           mavenLocal()

           maven {
               url "https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
           }
       }
   }

   apply plugin: "com.liferay.plugin"

   def SPRING_VERSION = "4.3.2.RELEASE"


    dependencies {
       compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.0.0"
       compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.util.taglib", version: "2.0.0"
       compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.spring.extender", version: "2.0.0"
       compile group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "2.0"
       compile group: "javax.servlet", name: "servlet-api", version: "2.5"
       compile group: "jstl", name: "jstl", version: "1.2"
       compile group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.compendium", version: "5.0.0"
       compile group: 'org.osgi', name: 'org.osgi.core', version: '5.0.0'
       // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc-portlet
       compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc-portlet', version: "$SPRING_VERSION"
       // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc
       compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: "$SPRING_VERSION"
       // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
       compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: "$SPRING_VERSION"
       // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core
       compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: "$SPRING_VERSION"
       // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context
       compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: "$SPRING_VERSION"
       // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans
       compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: "$SPRING_VERSION"
   }


   repositories {
       mavenLocal()

       maven {
           url "https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
       }
   }
   ```
5. /META-INF/views/view.jsp

   ```
   <%@ include file="/views/init.jsp" %>

   <p>
       <b><liferay-ui:message key="springmvcportlet_SpringMVCPortletmvcportlet.caption"/></b>
   </p>
   ```

   Any help would be Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out the tutorial on Liferay 7 and SpringMVC? Might find something there (you have the liferay descriptors, right?).

Comment: Here's the link to the tutorial: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/spring-mvc